# How to redirect direct link to a directory/file to a php page in ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have a simple php file, proposing a login to the user before to let him see a content, that is actually a preview of a video files.

Actually the video files are inside a directory (let's say `videoDir`) at the same level of the php file, so that I can access the php file like

http://someurl.com/index.php

and the video file like

http://someurl.com/videoDir/videoName.mov

http://someurl.com/videoDir/videoName2.mov

http://someurl.com/videoDir/videoName3.mov

Now, the login page let the user login correctly and then see the video preview, but, login or not, the user will always be able to download any video at his direct url (http://someurl.com/videoDir/videoName.mov) in this way.

So I was guessing if it is possible to redirect the direct url to the login page (maybe throught `.htaccess` ?) and what is the best way to do this ?

For your info : The page is on Ubuntu, managed by Apache.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add Below line In `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteRule ^/file/(.*)   /handleFiles.php?path=$1  [L]
```

And In `handleFiles.php` file Contents would be :

```
<?php
$auth = 0;
if (!isset($PHP_AUTH_USER))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
else
{
    if ($PHP_AUTH_USER == "UserName" and $PHP_AUTH_PW == "Password")
    {
        $auth=1;
        $file = implode('', file('/file/'.$path);
        print $file;
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        print "you need to login";
        exit;
    }
}

if ($auth==0) {
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: @SashaGrievus, Updated and tested the answer, Please check now & vote up if you find it helpful.

Comment: Oh, thank you! You included the php file as well. I'll try it. (sorry for the downvote, it wasn't me)

Comment: @SashaGrievus, Most welcome Bro, May be other answerer downvoted. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to disable a directory listing by the users. Open `.htacess` in your directory and put in next line:

```
Options -Indexes
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from local
```

Second, your `index.php` in any case will run as local script. Then, you must to check login status and send a file to download, like this:

```
// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './videoDir/videoName.mov';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: video/quicktime");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

You can read [`fpassthru` PHP function Documentation](https://www.php.net/fpassthru).